# FreeType will only render for a couple of seconds

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, freetype

So I have Been trying to implement Freetype to my 2D Engine and the text actually renders but only for one second or less and then it dissappears, already made sure that the render function is still been called, have no idea what could be wrong. Also it only renders the text on the Update function, when I try to render on Render it just wont pop up (this is driving me crazy, the functions are being called one after the other and nothing is modified).

Example:

```
TextRenderer* Text;

int main() {
    //OpenGL stuff
    Text = new Text(1920, 1080);
    Text->Load("fonts/arial.ttf",  24);
    while(window.isOpen) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwPollEvents();
        Update();
        Render();
        glfwSwapBuffers(m_window);
    }
}

void Update() {
    //Works for half a second
    Text->RenderText("Hello World", 200, 300, 1.0f);
}
void Render() {
    //Just wont work
    Text->RenderText("Hello World", 200, 300, 1.0f);
}
```

TextRenderer.cpp:

```
TextRenderer::TextRenderer(GLuint width, GLuint height)
{
    // Load and configure shader
    this->TextShader = Resources::LoadShader("shaders/text.vs", "shaders/text.frag", "text");
    this->TextShader.SetMatrix4("projection", glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(width), static_cast<GLfloat>(height), 0.0f), GL_TRUE);
    this->TextShader.SetInteger("text", 0);
    // Configure VAO/VBO for texture quads
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void TextRenderer::Load(std::string font, GLuint fontSize)
    {
        // First clear the previously loaded Characters
        this->Characters.clear();
        // Then initialize and load the FreeType library
        FT_Library ft;
        if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) // All functions return a value different than 0 whenever an error occurred
            std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library" << std::endl;
        // Load font as face
        FT_Face face;
        if (FT_New_Face(ft, font.c_str(), 0, &face))
            std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" << std::endl;
        // Set size to load glyphs as
        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontSize);
        // Disable byte-alignment restriction
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        // Then for the first 128 ASCII characters, pre-load/compile their characters and store them
        for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++) // lol see what I did there 
        {
            // Load character glyph 
            if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            {
                std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            // Generate texture
            GLuint texture;
            glGenTextures(1, &texture);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            glTexImage2D(
                GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                GL_RED,
                face->glyph->bitmap.width,
                face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
                0,
                GL_RED,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
            );
            // Set texture options
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

            // Now store character for later use
            Character character = {
                texture,
                glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
                glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
                face->glyph->advance.x
            };
            Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        // Destroy FreeType once we're finished
        FT_Done_Face(face);
        FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
    }

void TextRenderer::RenderText(std::string text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale, glm::vec3 color)
{
    // Activate corresponding render state  
    this->TextShader.Use();
    this->TextShader.SetVector3f("textColor", color);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

    // Iterate through all characters
    std::string::const_iterator c;
    for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++)
    {
        Character ch = Characters[*c];

        GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;

        GLfloat ypos = y + (this->Characters['H'].Bearing.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

        GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
        // Update VBO for each character
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
            { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 0.0 },
            { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 0.0 },

            { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 0.0 }
        };
        // Render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
        // Update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices); // Be sure to use glBufferSubData and not glBufferData

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        // Render quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        // Now advance cursors for next glyph
        x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale; // Bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (1/64th times 2^6 = 64)
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Comment: That sounds like your erasing and not redrawing the text. So probably not an error in the text-rendering (since it *do* render your text even if it only shows for a short time).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That sounds probable, where should I look then?

Comment: The code that *calls* `TextRenderer::RenderText` could be a good start.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the thing is that that's only one line of code `Text->RenderText("Press ENTER to start", 300.0f, 300, 1.0, iVec3(1.0f));` and I don't know what could be wrong there, the Text object is perfectly initialized, I already checked, and other objects which are not text render properly.

Comment: In your main render function, do you erase everything before drawing again? Will the `TextRenderer` objects you want to draw always be valid in that code? There could quite literally be *thousands* of reasons of this happening, but since you haven't provided us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's really impossible to tell you anything more.

Comment: You should also probably [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), including adding a lot of logging (even if it spams a little) to help you understand what's happening.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added the example, sorry for that. And I actually Log a lot, but tried to clean the code before posting it here. I use spdlog for Logging.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Hey if you could upload this to github I'd be happy to take a look =)

Comment: @AdaRaider give me your email or git username and I can add you to the repo!

Comment: @Aether You can add github username AdaRaider

Comment: Sent you the invitation, the folder gl_dev are the includes and libs.

Comment: @Aether cheers, I'm at work but I'll take a look today

Comment: @AdaRaider Thank you so much, please if you have any questions about the engine, just ask!

Comment: If your engine uses GL3+ core, try https://renderdoc.org/ . It helps a lot with mysterious rendering bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aether I got your engine runnning and while I don't yet have the answer as to why this is occuring (haven't had a thorough look yet) I can tell you that the issue does not occur if you don't update the camera. My gut feeling on this is that you have moved the camera or the text so that it is no longer in view but I'm hoping to add more to this when I can.

```
void Sandbox::Init() {

    AETHER_CLIENT_TRACE("Initialized LifeSandbox");
    GameManager::GameSpeed = 1;

    Resources::LoadTexture("textures/default.png", "default");
    Resources::LoadTexture("textures/emoji.png", "emoji");
    Resources::LoadShader("shaders/spriteVertexShader.bin", "shaders/spriteFragmentShader.bin", "sprite");
    Renderer = new Renderer2D(Resources::GetShader("sprite"));
    Text->Load("fonts/arial.TTF", 24);
    MainCamera = new Camera();  
}

void Sandbox::Update() 
{       
    //MainCamera->Update(iVec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
}

void Sandbox::Render() 
{
  //Works fine
  Text->RenderText("Press ENTER to start", 0, 0, 1.0, iVec3(2.0f));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Been looking to the Camera code, think it has to do with the view2D uniform, the text shader doesnt't have that uniform and is really only that what gets modified when the Update is called. I will try adding that Uniform to the Shader and will Update with the results.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't get a chance to dig any deeper but good luck!